# No http service - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

I can't seem to start my printer spooler service because some of the dependencies have not started.

So I looked at the dependencies in the options menu.
I found that there was no HTTP service in my `services.msc`. So I started looking into how to install the HTTP service manually.

I've gone into `Add Programs and Features` in the menu and installed all the `IIS` and `World Wide Web Publishing` services, but with no avail.

I am trying to install the HTTP service on a development machine which already has an Apache service running. I don't know if this could have an impact on the HTTP service.

Basically I need to know one of two things:

1 - How to install the HTTP service manually from a DLL (I don't think its possible)

2 - How to rectify the problem so that the HTTP service is installed so that I can start the printer spooler.

**Just a side note** the `winhttp.dll` file is in my system 32 folder.

`search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20system32&crumb=filename%3A~<Winhttp.dll%20OR%20System.Generic.String%3AWinhttp.dll&crumb=location:C%3A%5CWINDOWS%5Csystem32`

**EDIT (showing results for `sc qc spooler` from cmd) from @w32sh**

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

Comment: Although "http" driver is listed as one of the dependencies for Spooler service in a clean Windows installation, Spooler can function even without http. What happens when you start the Spooler service? if you're getting Error 1068, then run this command (from a Command Prompt window) and post the output:

`sc qc spooler`

Comment: @w32sh The results were too long for the comment section (And wouldn't be formatted) so I ran the command and added the results to the question window

Comment: @w32sh Perfect that worked like a bomb, once I was on the right track it was easy. So the `http` driver/service was disabled so I used the following command to enable it `sc config http start= demand` which I got from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx, from there on I was able to start the service, if you post all this in an answer then I will accept it. Printer Spooler service is also working now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Services MMC doesn't list `http`, as it's a driver and not exactly a service.

These two commands will tell you how http driver is configured and what happens whey they start. From Admin Command Prompt, type:

```
sc qc http
```

To start http driver:

```
net start http
```

(the latter will try to start `http`, and shows an error code if it fails to start.)

Comment: If you run into an error trying to start it, it may be due to a registry setting and the solution can be found here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1950478-server-2012-r2-standard-services-failing-to-start

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Win32Guy** and **Jacques Koekemoer** for the wonderful work, interpretation & Technet link. 
[SC : Microsoft Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx)

I want to take into account the broader aspects, keep **Print Spooler** in the center & develop an understanding. I want to mention:

1. Print Spooler Dependency Tree, i.e., The system components Print Spooler depends upon:

   1. **Print Spooler (Spooler)** depends on **Remote Procedure Call (RPCSS)** & **HTTP Service (HTTP)**
   2. RPCSS depends on **DCOM Server Process Launcher (DcomLaunch)** & **RPC Endpoint Mapper (RpcEptMapper)**
   3. HTTP doesn't have any dependencies.
   4. Dcomlaunch & RpcEptMapper doesn't have any dependencies.
   5. So now we have found the proper tree & roots. We have to start with the roots!
   6. HTTP is not a service & a driver, but all the others are services & are located in/by services.msc. You can't find HTTP there.
   7. A question arises, how to work with/on HTTP? **sc** commands are good to work with HTTP as well as services mentioned in services.msc.
2. What are the ideal configurations for the **Five**?
   I have ideal configurations on my pc/os for all the five. I will run the **sc qc** command for the five & show the info here so that anyone can check/match with that as below :

```
C:\Users\LittlePro>sc qc DcomLaunch
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: DcomLaunch
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : DCOM Server Process Launcher
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem

C:\Users\LittlePro>sc qc RpcEptMapper
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: RpcEptMapper
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : RPC Endpoint Mapper
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

C:\Users\LittlePro>sc qc RPCSS
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: RPCSS
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k rpcss
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
        DEPENDENCIES       : RpcEptMapper
                           : DcomLaunch
        SERVICE_START_NAME: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

C:\Users\LittlePro>sc qc http
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: HTTP
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : HTTP Service
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :

C:\Users\LittlePro>sc qc Spooler
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: Spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

3. Start from the roots & make the configuration changes with command **sc config**

4.**I think** one can use the **net start** command to start any service, once it has been configured properly. (if needed!)

5. What sir Win32Guy says about the dependency of spooler upon HTTP :
   "Although "HTTP" driver is listed as one of the dependencies for Spooler service in a clean Windows installation, Spooler can function even without HTTP "
   So, perhaps this link is a solution for some people :
   ["Fix Spooler Service Error 1068 “The dependency service or group failed to start” By sir Ramesh Srinivasan](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-spooler-service-error-1068-dependency-failed/)
   But I am looking for a Real solution!

**( These configurations are identical in win 7, win 8 & win 10 32/64 . So, this thread is workable through all of them )**

( These links can come handy for services under services.msc :
[How to Restore Default Services in Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236709-services-restore-default-services-windows-7-a.html)

[Black Viper’s Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) )

Comment: I am submitting this comment to nearly every one of your answers.  We do not consider greetings, salutations, or signatures to be helpful.  So please avoid using this in your answers in the future.  Specifically to this answer, if you are going to refer to another user, best to link to their profile when you do.  A year and a half later, it's difficult to understand, who you are referring to since the user changes their username.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that WinQuic is listed as a dependency of HTTP, and HTTP is a dependency of the Print Spooler service.  WinQuic appeared to be missing following an update to Windows 10 1809:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc qc winquic 
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: 
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

The solution was to export the registry keys from a working 1809 PC:
[Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinQuic]

The keys were merged, then the system rebooted.  The Print Spooler service was running and all missing printers reappeared.

Comment: Nice to know that you solved your problem,  but how is anybody else supposed to use this answer?

Comment: Comment above nonwithstanding, this TOTALLY HELPED ME.  I spent 4 hours with a coworker trying to figure out what was wrong with her Print Spooler post-update, and this worked for us.  Thank you!