# Win10 v1709 - HTTP service stopped working

Tags: windows-10, services

As I found out, this problem not only affects KeePass, but all (Windows) services that use HTTP, too. Therefore, I adapted my original question.

---

**The specs:**

- Win10 v1709, all the latest updates
- .NET Framework 3.5 & 4.7 checked in Windows Features
- [`World Wide Web Services` & `IIS Management Console` checked in Windows Features](https://superuser.com/questions/416712/how-to-re-install-http-windows-service)
- Services are set up like out-of-the-box
- `Visual Studio Community 2017` with `.NET desktop development`
- No CCleaner/manual registry "tweaks" whatsoever

The first thing that I noticed was that KeePass 2's HTTP-Plugin stopped working after updating KeePass (this does not make much sense, but I did nothing else at that time).

Now, when starting KeePass 2, it throws the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

> ```
> The .NET HttpListener is not supported on your OS
> ```

The KeePassHttp-Plugin now refuses to work with browser-plugins.

Later on, I found out that all services that require HTTP Service - which is not listed in my Services Window - stopped functioning. So for example, the Print Spooler service stopped working. When I try to start it it says:

[image: screenshot 2]

> ```
> Windows could not start the Print Spooler service on Local Computer.
> Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.
> ```

`Error 1068` is displayed on all those services. I googled it, but found no (working) solution.

I tried `sfc /scannow`, booting into Safe Mode, enabling/disabling all services - all to no avail. Also, `DISM` does not show any corruptions.

Another lead was [No http service - Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1059068/no-http-service-windows-10):

> ```
> C:\> sc qc http
> [SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS
> SERVICE_NAME: http
>    TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
>    START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
>    ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
>    BINARY_PATH_NAME   : system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
>    LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
>    TAG                : 0
>    DISPLAY_NAME       : HTTP Service
>    DEPENDENCIES       :
>    SERVICE_START_NAME :
>
> C:\> sc queryex http
> SERVICE_NAME: http
>    TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
>    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
>    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 183  (0xb7)
>    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
>    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
>    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
>    PID                : 0
>    FLAGS              :
>
> C:\> sc start http
> [SC] StartService FAILED 183:
> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
>
> C:\> net start http
> System error 183 has occurred.
> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
>
> C:\> sc queryex spooler
> SERVICE_NAME: spooler
>    TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  (interactive)
>    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
>    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1068  (0x42c)
>    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
>    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
>    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
>    PID                : 0
>    FLAGS              :
>
> C:\>sc start spooler
> [SC] StartService FAILED 1068:
> The dependency service or group failed to start.
> ```

---

`System error 183` seems to be a lead, but unfortunately, Google provided little help in resolving this.

Also, Event Viewer revealed nothing new (in my opinion):

[See this link for the XML of all HTTP-related events](https://pastebin.com/zyA4K4FY) (all of them were warnings, by the way). All of them recur after a restart.

Apart from performing a clean install (or at least one of Win10's reset options), is there some option to get things running again?

Comment: You checked if the services were installed doesn’t mean they are running

Comment: @Ramhound absolutely - but starting the HTTP service (`net start http` or `sc start http`, I assume) did not work. I added `sc start` & `sc queryex` results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling about every update, feature and module, the problem still persisted. I then tried to use a `http.sys` from my other computer - this did not help, either.

Therefore, unfortunately, we will never find out, as I now solved it by cleanly reinstalling Win10.