# Unwanted changes on services window. Now, my os works funny

Tags: services, print-spooler

I was Looking for a solution to fix my printer problem, and I found the linked posted below.

[No http service - Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1059068/no-http-service-windows-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I was searching through the services window of my computer for information when I started one of the services COM+, two available. With the hope of solving the problem with my printer.

COM+ System application 
COM+ Event System

I would like to know how to restore the previous configuration.

This is my situation now:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Red>sc qc spooler
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem

C:\Users\Red>sc qc http
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: http
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : HTTP Service
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :

C:\Users\Red>sc qc DcomLaunch
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: DcomLaunch
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch -p
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : DCOM Server Process Launcher
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem

C:\Users\Red>sc qc RpcEptMapper
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: RpcEptMapper
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS -p
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : RPC Endpoint Mapper
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

C:\Users\Red>sc qc RPCSS
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: RPCSS
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k rpcss -p
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
        DEPENDENCIES       : RpcEptMapper
                           : DcomLaunch
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

C:\Users\Red>sc qc http
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: http
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : HTTP Service
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :

C:\Users\Red>sc qc Spooler
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: Spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

My log on command prompt It's very similar to Vineet Garg. Except for the `-p` at the end of some lines.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS -p

I would like to find out if the consequences of the changes I made in my computer are serious and to fix the strange behaivour of my os.

Thank you

I made some changes, I plugged printer's USB on the port that showed on my command prompt, also I run a troubleshooter problem on the printer, I deleted two drivers I had extra from the printer.

Now is working fine,  I checked the services and everything on print spooler stills the same.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What exactly is the problem you're experiencing? Your question may be suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Please clarify the actual problem you're trying to solve and be sure to make your question title reflect your actual question. Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really there shouldn't be any worry about having activated those two services. You may restart and it should be back to normal, as long as you didn't change the startup type to automatic. You may try starting the service 'Print Spooler' to see if it would help with your printer problems. Although your question is broad, I would hazard a guess and say the printing issue isn't related to these services.

On restoring to a previous state:

If you had it setup, you can restore from a backup.

`Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore (Windows 7)` (I don't know why it's still called Windows 7 in Windows 10)

Or alernatively search for backup and restore.

Another method you may try is creating a recovery USB and trying the repair options there. There are different options ranging factory reset to a simple repair.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried to print the demo page. first windows said that the printer couldn't do it, in the second try says there is an error state. I also tried to print offline with the same result.  I would like to fix the problem before restarting the computer understanding the changes I made. Does anyone know a place where to learn more about the services and their relationship between them?

Comment: I would look for the model version of your printer and search online for drivers and support. Off the top of the my head I know that Brother printers require drivers downloaded from their site and installed to be able to run, as Windows may not have the correct drivers automatically installed for you. Have you tried printing the demo page without using the computer? It should be in your manual, and will tell you the status of the cartridges/etc. If even that doesn't work, I would physically inspect the ink cartridges (peeling the protective tape off is commonly missed) and paper tray.